# Python Spyder: breakpoints working only once in a blue moon

Tags: python, spyder

I use Spyder 2.3.5.2 on an Anaconda Python installation running on Windows 7 64 bit.

The debug functionalities are very temperamental and unreliable. My breakpoints  are often completely ignored. Sometimes applying the IT approach (closing and restarting the program) solves the issue, but more often than not it doesn't.
Some forums recommend running the program in the current ipython console, but that doesn't help, either.

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get Sypder to stop at break points (inserted with f12).  But then in reading the docs I realized I needed to switch to debug mode (Ctrl-f5 or Debug->Debug).  This switches the IPython console prompt to:

```
ipdb>
```

Once in this mode, break statements work.